# Can't register user at node : not_allowed

Tags: ios, ejabberd

I am trying to do the server setup in order to build a jabber client in iOS. I am following this link :

http://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/building-a-jabber-client-for-ios-server-setup--mobile-6958

However when I try to run the postinstall.sh script in terminal as follows :

```
Mac-mini:bin user$ ./start
Mac-mini:bin user$ ./postinstall.sh nitin localhost pass

   -=- ejabberd post installation script -=- 
          (c) 2005-2016 ProcessOne 

* Checking ejabberd installation

* Starting ejabberd instance
ERROR: The ejabberd node 'ejabberd@localhost' is already running.

* Creating administrator user
Can't register user nitin@localhost at node ejabberd@localhost:    not_allowed

* Stopping ejabberd instance
==> Setup finished
```

As shown above I get this error :

```
Can't register user nitin@localhost at node ejabberd@localhost: not_allowed
```

Let me know of some solution. Thanks.

Comment: Check for ip_access & registration_timeout in ejabberd.yml

Comment: provide ejabberd configuration.it seems you are missing configuration.

Answer (score 0):

You probably are using the wrong Operating System user and do not have access to the Erlang cookie file that allows Erlang Internodes communication.

This is required to perform all ejabberdctl commands.

You can read about Erlang cookies here: https://docs.ejabberd.im/admin/guide/security/#erlang-cookie